# Cannot read post parameters from req.body in Express.js 4.13.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ionic-framework

**Objective:** I'm new to Node.js and Express.js framework. Currently I'm writing a small app using IONIC framework where I trying to pass user basic details like FirstName, LastName to node.js server as a matter of first step. Then once I read the data I'm planning to save the data in the database.

**Issue:** Currently when I pass the details (in this case just FirstName for testing purpose) through POST request from my app to the node js server and when i try to access the FirstName using `req.body.FirstName`, the server returns `"undefined"`.However when I use `console.log(req.body)` it returns the value for `eg., { '{"FirstName":"test"}': '' }.`

I'm not sure where did I miss. I suppose I referred a lot of links thru Google, nothing seems to be working out. It might be a simple thing, but it is bothering me lot and I'm wasting time to find the solution.

Configuration:
Express.js - 4.13.3

I've tried different combination based on the related links for this issue. Nothing seems to be working. Any guidance or advise will be really helpful as I got struck in this.

serverapp.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  console.log("Hi from server", req.body);
  console.log("Hi this is key value", req.body.FirstName); // this throws error as undefined

});

  var server = app.listen(8100, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Code snippet from Controllers.js - Post request is sent via this.

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8100'
       var request = $http.post(url,
                {'FirstName': $scope.Model.FName}, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}});
```

Rego.html file

```
<form name="tab-Registration.form">
                <div class="list" align="left">

                    <label class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="FName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="Model.FName" class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                    </label>
                    <label class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="LName" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="Model.LName" class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                    </label>
                    <label class="all_page_bgColor" align="left"> <!-- class="item item-input"  -->
                        <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="Model.Email" class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                    </label>
                    <label class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="PhoneNo" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="Model.PhoneNo" class="all_page_bgColor" align="left">
                    </label>

                </div>
                <div align = "center">
                    <button class="button button-assertive"  ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This object `{ '{"FirstName":"test"}': '' }` has only one key which is `{"FirstName":"test"}` and the value is empty string. Actually the whole object is the key of first value.

Object must be like this: `{"FirstName":"test"}`

But i don't know how things end up like this. You have FName in your form but you get this, and I don't know what this IONIC framework is and how it works. I think it's better to start with experimenting with express.js then switch to higher level frameworks.

Comment: I tried to  use the following                                                                          var keys = Object.keys(req.body);                                                                          console.log(keys[0])                                                                                         returns {"FirstName":"Baranidharan"} but unable to read value for FirstName. If anyone can advise, that'll be of great help for me

Comment: @Brad The key must be FirstName not {"FirstName":"Baranidharan"}

Comment: Thanks for your updates. And I tried using keys[0].FirstName, but it still it returns undefined. Unsure how to resolve this. If i didn't get any value from req.body then it's a different issue. I got the value here and couldn't read it. Really got struck for a while and could not proceed. Not sure if i'm missing a little thing since i'm new. If you could or anyone could help that'll be really helpful..

Comment: @brad you are getting incorrect data, the problem is from client side not the server side. I don't know your client is using URLEncoded format or json, but probably it's using JSON but you use URLEncoded parser.

Comment: I'm using the following from client side which means that it is urlencoded.                                                                                                       var url = 'http://localhost:8100'
       var request = $http.post(url,
                {'FirstName': $scope.Model.FName}, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}})

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this. The solution is to use transformRequest while sending the request to the server for URL encoded data, coz the request send to server by default sends Json object. And when you want to over-ride that, you have to use transformRequest

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
                },

                data: {
                FirstName: $scope.Model.FName}
```